# Need to move sections up and down in crystal report programmatically

Tags: crystal-reports

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7FZx.jpg)We need to move sections up and down in crystal report programmatically but couldn't get any code to do this rather GUI which is available in report itself (see URL:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6tUUUZ-q2s). Same functionally as in above URL needs as a program. Need to move already defined section sections in crystal reports up and down based on pre-defined sequence that can be through Database.
For example:-
Section1, Section2, Section3 having sequence 1, 2, 3 in crystal report. Now if the sequence change to 2, 3, 1 then sections should move up and down as Section2, Section3 and Section1 in crystal report when print/executed.

Comment: Do you want to set the order of the sections dinamically? May you show your design (screenshot)?

Comment: Yes you are right, need to set the order of the sections dynamically...unable to attach snapshot. [Hint: Sections are nothing but details section in crystal report need to move up and down dyanamicaly]

Comment: Directly not possible. We have done such things using groups (reorder groups by formula). And because I never open linked images here, then I can't be sure that I understood your needs correctly.

Comment: Arvo nailed it. Did you get it yet? If not, show your data model and design (rpt).